# Text label not showing up

Tags: python, tkinter

I have changed everything on other answers but nothing works.

```
from tkinter import * 
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter
import pynput 
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
from tkinter import filedialog

charCount = 0
keys = []
press_value = 0

root = Tk()
my_menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=my_menu)

def label1(root):
    label = tkinter.Label(root, text = "correct")
    label.pack()

def pressOn():
    button_1.configure(fg = "Green", text = "ON")

def pressOff():
    button_1.configure(fg = "red", text = "OFF")

class Window(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

                                           
def save_location():
    location_window = Tk()
    var = StringVar()
    var.set('No Folder Selected')
    locationLabel = Label(location_window, textvariable=var.get())
    locationLabel.place(x=70,y=20)
    location_window.update()
    def browse_button():
        filename = filedialog.askdirectory()
        print(filename)
        var = filename
    button2 = Button(location_window, text="Browse", command=browse_button).grid(row=1, column=0)
    location_window.title('Save Location')
    location_window.iconbitmap('C:/Users/Gaming/Downloads/floppydisk.ico')
    location_window.geometry('250x100')
    location_window.mainloop()

file_menu = Menu(my_menu, tearoff=False)
my_menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=file_menu)
file_menu.add_command(label="New...", command=label1)
file_menu.add_command(label="Exit", command=root.quit)

#Create an edit menu item

edit_menu = Menu(my_menu, tearoff=False)
my_menu.add_cascade(label="Edit", menu=edit_menu)
edit_menu.add_command(label="Save Location", command=save_location)
edit_menu.add_command(label="Copy", command=label1)

def buttonPress():
    global press_value
    press_value = press_value + 1
    if (press_value % 2) == 0:
        pressOff()
    else:
        pressOn()

button_1 = tkinter.Button(text="OFF", width = '10', height = '10', fg = 'red', command = buttonPress)
button_1.pack(side = 'bottom')
```

If you click 'edit' and then'save location'. It pops up with a box but should show a label about the directory people can choose by picking the browse button. It is not working though, the label is not showing. Thanks for everyone's help in advance.

Comment: You want `textvariable=var`, not `textvariable=var.get()`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It still doesn't display the label on the screen.

Comment: A much more serious problem that I didn't notice at first: you're calling `Tk()` more than once, which causes all sorts of issues such as variables not working.  Use `Toplevel()` instead to create additional windows.

Comment: is that all I need to do to fix it. Replace that one thing?